# vim size is not full size as teminal

Tags: ubuntu, vim

[image]

you can see in the screenshot that at right and bottom side vim having space. how do I solve this? I have tried some option but still, it is not working.

```
$ echo $TERM
```

output: xterm-256color

Comment: Where are the spaces? I don't see any problem...

Comment: @Kent see the screenshot terminal window is full screen, vim editor has some space/padding on bottom and right side.

Answer (score 3):

Terminal emulators use a grid for display. The dimensions of each cell of the grid and thus of the grid itself are determined by the metrics and the size of the font, and any other geometry setting available in your terminal emulator.

Those "spaces" are there because the inner-dimensions of the terminal window are different from the dimensions of the grid.

You could get rid of that padding:

- by finding the exact font metrics that match your windows dimensions (this is silly),
- or by making sure your windows dimensions always match the grid, this is called "hints" in most Linux window managers,
- or by setting the background color of your terminal emulator to the same color as your Vim colorscheme's background color.